# How do I download a large json file from internet without parsing it (java, okhttp3)?

Tags: java, json, okhttp, fileoutputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am facing an issue while downloading a large json file from internet (20+GB), specifically how it's being saved to the local disk. I don't want to parse the json, just download it.

There are several similar questions answered in SO, but i haven't seen people have issues with the output - I am not sure what I'm missing.

Anyways, when I execute the following code, it downloads the json and puts the corresponding byte array into file, and not save it in string format.

```
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(path)
        .header("User-Agent", ClientConstants.USER_AGENT)
        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .build();

    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        log.error("failed download for url : {0}, with status code {1}", url, response.code());
        if (response.body() != null) {
            response.body().close();
        }
        throw new IOException("failed download for url=" + url);
    }
    else {
        try(BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(response.body().byteStream())){
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[10000];
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(this.downloadFilePath);
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(readBuffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                outputStream.flush();
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("failed download for url=" + url, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem ? You can not read/parse json file after download ?  I assume it is because of the following header `Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"` you have this file zipped. So if you wrap your input stream into [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) it should unpack it automatically. But check it first with some smaller test file.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. I was actually using a different feed to download a zip when i needed that header. But forgot to take it out when i downloaded a json. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

The code works. I just had to remove the incorrect header as Victor Gubin suggested.